# In React, making contents of a component available to child components without relying on a chain of props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have kind of a unique situation. I'm building a react app with a web version and a desktop version (run by NW.js). They essentially have the same UI, but there are some differences in functionality between the desktop and the web version. I want to reuse the exact UI code base, but depending on whether its web or local, wrap the  component with another component that provides the necessary differing functionality. (As an example of this, there's a button that launches a desktop process. If you're on web and you click the button, it will use a URL schema to launch the local app and then run it, but if you're local it'll just run it).

The idea is that the function that either launches the app through the URL schema or simply launches the desktop process will be referenced in the single UI codebase, but do nothing unless the alternate functionality is provided by the wrapper component.

The question I have is, how can I get the functionality in the wrapper component to the correct child component without having to pass it down through a chain of props from top to bottom? I'm thinking of, for example, how Provider works in React-redux, making the store available to the other components without relying on props, provided you use the proper functions/hooks to access it.

I hope my explanation of what I'm thinking is clear. Please let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: Use https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

Context is the React sanctioned way of doing things:

```js
// MyWrapperComponent.js
import { createContext } from 'react';

const MyAppContext = createContext();

const MyWrapperComponent = () => {
   return (
     <MyAppContext.Provider value={someValue}>
       <App/>
     </MyAppContext.Provider>
   );
};

// SomeDeeplyNestedComponent.js
const SomeDeeplyNestedComponent = () => {
   const thing = useContext(MyAppContext);
   return <Something/>
}
```